# Llegar a la url que debería tener una función que devuelva un HTML, Django no lo muestra y devuelve TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

Quiero mostrar un archivo html cuando vaya a http://localhost:8000/signup/.

Intenté esta views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def signupuser(request):
    return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html')
```

Y aqui esta `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name="signupuser")
]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\todowoo\todo\views.py", line 5, in signupuser
    return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html')
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: todo/signupuser.html
[20/Oct/2020 19:10:08] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78389
```

Pero el template existe, esta en `C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\todowoo\todo\migrations\templates\todo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django por defecto hace la búsqueda de templates a partir de los directorios que representan apps dentro de tu proyecto y sus subdirectiors `templates`. En tu caso, la ruta que proporcionas pareciera tratarse de un proyecto llamado `todowoo`, en una app llamada `todo` y más especificamente en su directorio `migrations`,  a partir de este último directorio es donde esta el problema. El directorio migrations lleva el historial de los cambios registrados sobre los modelos que se ven reflejados en la base de datos, este directorio (por defecto) no está relacionado con los templates.

Para que Django pueda encontrar tu archivo html tienes varias opciones:

1. Seguir con la configuración por defecto de Django. Simplificando un poco la explicación dire que mi directorio raíz `\` es igual a tu directio raiz del proyecto `C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Django\todowoo\`.
   A partir de los anterior tus templates deben encontrarse en el directorio `\{nombre_app}\templates\`

**Nota.** Es importante notar que crear un subdirectorio  dentro de la carpeta templates con el nombre de la app no es obligatorio, esto se hace para hacer namespaces de templates y evitar colisiones entre los nombres que se les asignan a estas.

2. Modificar la configuración por defecto de Django. Como se menciona anteriormente, Django por defecto hace la búsqueda de las templates dentro de la subcarpeta templates en cada app, este comportamiento puede ser cambiado para que  la búsqueda se haga en alguna otra carpeta, una práctica común es hacer la búsqueda sobre una única carpeta `templates` localizada en la raíz del  proyecto. Para mayor información de como realizar esto, checa la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration) pero en resumen el único cambio seria en el archivo settings.

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
    },
]
```